# How to automatically listener function on Socket IO

Tags: javascript, php, function, sockets, websocket

Hello i want to try change icon notification,
I'm already try chat with other user with socket io success,

But i have a new problem when user want to know get new notification
(in other menu or after login).

when try have new notification, this function not working,
i want when have new notification the id **#notification_chat**
automatically add class **.faa-ring**

This is my file

File **server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http, {
  cors: {
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
  }
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on("reload-notif", function(){
    socket.broadcast.emit("reload-notif");
  });

  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

http.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0' ,function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

File **index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .faa-ring {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://localhost:2028/chat">
      <i id="notification_chat" class="fa fa-comment animated"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- jQuery 3 -->
    <script src="http://localhost:2028/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Socket.IO -->
    <script src="localhost:/assets/vendor/socket.io/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const socketIoAddress = "http://localhost:3000";
        const socket = io(socketIoAddress);

        // i want if have new notification, this socket run automatically 
        socket.emit('reload-notif'); 
        socket.on('reload-notif', () => {
            notification_chat();
        });

        function notification_chat() {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://localhost:2028/chat/notification', 
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: "html", 
              success: function(data) {
                 if(data=="0"){
                    $("#notification_chat").removeClass("faa-ring");
                 }
                 else {
                    $("#notification_chat").addClass("faa-ring");
                 }
              }
          });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Help me thank's